# Windows 10 and Ubuntu both installed in UEFI mode but no Windows entry in grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

Hello I recently installed Ubuntu on my machine so that I could dual boot it alongside my existing windows 10 installation. However, there is not option to boot into Windows 10 from grub. I have checked to make sure that both operating systems are installed in UEFI mode. Additionally os-prober return nothing in terminal. Any suggestions for how I can get grub to recognize my Windows installation?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for not being able to comment. But have you accessed your bootloader pressing "F12" right after you start your system or the equivalent key to load the BIOS menu instead of going to GRUB, just to make sure your Windows is still there?

Comment: Yes I have and I have also been able to successfully boot into by Windows 10 installation

Comment: During Installation, you're sure you installed your root partition on the proper device? @Ludwig

Answer (score 0):

First boot into Ubuntu and run `os-prober` command in terminal. It will show all the bootable drives. And then run `sudo update-grub`. This should solve the problem if it is possible to solve.

Else the boot drive for windows is corrupted. If thats the case then nothing other than reinstalling windows will work.

Comment: As stated in the original question os-prober returns nothing however I can still boot into and use my Windows installation.

Comment: @Ludwig sorry i somehow missed that part. I will edit my answer accordingly